# Error with encoding a base64 String

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have the following code:

```
@IBAction func loadData(sender: AnyObject) {

    let plainString = "foo"
    let plainData = (plainString as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let base64String = plainData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.fromRaw(0)!)
    println(base64String) // Zm9v

    let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.fromRaw(0)!)
    let decodedString = NSString(data: decodedData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    println(decodedString) // foo


}
```

But i got the error: NSData? does not have a member named "base64EncodeString withOptions

what i have to change in the code?

Comment: Most of the Swift questions about *"does not have a member named"* are simply caused by the fact that an optional is not unwrapped, and the question mark in the error message `NSData? does not have ...` shows that this is also the case here. – I don't want to sound rude, but the error message is quite clear. And if you click on `plainData` in Xcode then you will see the type `NSData?` in the Help inspector.

Comment: Yes it is Declaired as NSData?

Comment: Do you know what that means? Have you read about optionals and unwrapping?